# read XML in SQL, no data being pulled

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to retrieve data from an XML file.  Below is how the XML doc looks and below that is my SQL code.  It will run the code and show column headers - but will not populate with any data.  What am I missing?

```
<profile xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/mma/v1/participants-profile.xsd" generated="2015-12-10T17:34:54Z">
<fighters>
<fighter id="01585452-852a-4b40-a6dc-fdd04279f02c" height="72" weight="170" reach="" stance="" first_name="Sai" nick_name="The Boss" last_name="Wang">
  <record wins="6" losses="4" draws="1" no_contests="0" />
  <born date="1988-01-16" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
  <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
</fighter>
<fighter id="0168dd6b-b3e1-4954-8b71-877a63772dec" height="" weight="0" reach="" stance="" first_name="Enrique" nick_name="Wasabi" last_name="Marin">
  <record wins="8" losses="2" draws="0" no_contests="0" />
  <born date="" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
  <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
</fighter>
```

---

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = P
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Python27\outputMMA.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS         FIGHTERS(P)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/fighters/fighter', 1) --1\ IS ATTRIBUTES AND 2 IS     ELEMENTS
WITH (
    id varchar(100),
    height varchar(10),
    last_name varchar(100)  

) --THIS IS WHERE YOU SELECT FIELDS you want returned

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: `FOR OPENXML` is [deprecated](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1609/replacing-openxml-with-the-xml-nodes-function-in-sql-server-2005/) See my answer how to use today's approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly repair the data (`:xs`, `</fighters>`, `</profile>`)

```
<profile xmlns:xs="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/mma/v1/participants-profile.xsd" generated="2015-12-10T17:34:54Z">
<fighters>
<fighter id="01585452-852a-4b40-a6dc-fdd04279f02c" height="72" weight="170" reach="" stance="" first_name="Sai" nick_name="The Boss" last_name="Wang">
  <record wins="6" losses="4" draws="1" no_contests="0" />
  <born date="1988-01-16" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
  <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
</fighter>
<fighter id="0168dd6b-b3e1-4954-8b71-877a63772dec" height="" weight="0" reach="" stance="" first_name="Enrique" nick_name="Wasabi" last_name="Marin">
  <record wins="8" losses="2" draws="0" no_contests="0" />
  <born date="" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
  <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
</fighter>
</fighters>
</profile>
```

Then the code

```
FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, 'profile/fighters/fighter', 1)
```

and we are done

```
 01585452-852a-4b40-a6dc-fdd04279f02c   72  Wang
 0168dd6b-b3e1-4954-8b71-877a63772dec       Marin
```

Comment: I only copied the top part of the file - so the answer was the ':xs'.  Thanks!  What does that do - and why might it have been missing??

Comment: @Jason Vondersmith, XML documents can have undeclared namespaces. You did not mistype anything and neither is your document in error.

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` is deprecated and should only be thought of in very special performance related situations...

Answer (score 1):

`FROM OPENXML` is not the best approach any more. Try it like this:

Just copy this into an empty query window and execute:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<profile xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/mma/v1/participants-profile.xsd" generated="2015-12-10T17:34:54Z">
  <fighters>
    <fighter id="01585452-852a-4b40-a6dc-fdd04279f02c" height="72" weight="170" reach="" stance="" first_name="Sai" nick_name="The Boss" last_name="Wang">
      <record wins="6" losses="4" draws="1" no_contests="0" />
      <born date="1988-01-16" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
      <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
    </fighter>
    <fighter id="0168dd6b-b3e1-4954-8b71-877a63772dec" height="" weight="0" reach="" stance="" first_name="Enrique" nick_name="Wasabi" last_name="Marin">
      <record wins="8" losses="2" draws="0" no_contests="0" />
      <born date="" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
      <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city="" />
    </fighter>
  </fighters>
</profile>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/mma/v1/participants-profile.xsd')
SELECT One.fighter.value('@id','uniqueidentifier') AS Fighter_ID
      ,One.fighter.value('@height','int') AS Fighter_Height      
      ,One.fighter.value('@weight','int') AS Fighter_Weigth      
      ,One.fighter.value('@reach','varchar(100)') AS Fighter_Height      
      ,One.fighter.value('@stance','varchar(100)') AS Fighter_Height      
      ,One.fighter.value('@first_name','varchar(100)') AS Fighter_FirstName
      ,One.fighter.value('@nick_name','varchar(100)') AS Fighter_NickName
      ,One.fighter.value('@last_name','varchar(100)') AS Fighter_LastName
      ,One.fighter.value('record[1]/@wins','int') AS FighterRecord_Wins
      ,One.fighter.value('record[1]/@draws','int') AS FighterRecord_Draws
      ,One.fighter.value('record[1]/@no_contests','int') AS FighterRecord_NoContest
      ,One.fighter.value('born[1]/@date','date') AS FighterBorn_Date
      ,One.fighter.value('born[1]/@country_code','varchar(10)') AS FighterBorn_CountryCode
      ,One.fighter.value('born[1]/@country','varchar(100)') AS FighterBorn_Country
      ,One.fighter.value('born[1]/@state','varchar(100)') AS FighterBorn_State
      ,One.fighter.value('born[1]/@city','varchar(100)') AS FighterBorn_City
      ,One.fighter.value('out_of[1]/@country_code','varchar(10)') AS FighterOutOf_CountryCode
      ,One.fighter.value('out_of[1]/@country','varchar(100)') AS FighterOutOf_Country
      ,One.fighter.value('out_of[1]/@state','varchar(100)') AS FighterOutOf_State
      ,One.fighter.value('out_of[1]/@city','varchar(100)') AS FighterOutOf_City
FROM @xml.nodes('/profile/fighters/fighter') AS One(fighter)
```

Comment: Consider altering your solution from a declared XML string in query to parsing from file as OP originally set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have an undeclared namespace in your XML document. Consider the revision declaring the namespace and referencing it in xpath expression:

```
DECLARE @x xml;    
SELECT @x = P
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Python27\outputMMA.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS FIGHTERS(P)

DECLARE @hdoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x,
    '<root xmlns:doc="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/mma/v1/participants-profile.xsd"/>'

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/doc:profile/doc:fighters/doc:fighter', 1)  
WITH (
      id varchar(100),
      height varchar(10),
      last_name varchar(100)      
     ) 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` is deprecated and should only be thought of in very special performance related situations...